# -[NSBitmapImageRep representationUsingType:properties:] export specific BMP configuration?

Tags: cocoa, bitmap, nsimage, nsimagerep

I'm trying to figure out how to export BMP data from an NSBitmapImageRep, but it doesn't appear there are any properties I can add to specify how the BMP should be created. Specifically, I wanted to export one that is ARGB8 (that is, alpha, red, green, blue 8 bits each). How is the output supposed to be structured when I pass the type NSBMPFileType in, and is there a way to change the way this outputs? If not, can anyone recommend a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?